# Can't send a proper pdf file via phpmailer AddAttachment

Tags: php, pdf, addition, phpmailer, attachment

```
    private function mailToClient($file, $customer, $trans_id = "")
{
    if(!$customer["email"]) return;
    $mail = &$this->getMailObject();
    $country = $_SESSION[PROJECT]["user"]["details"]["country"];
    $lang = getLanguage();

    if( empty($trans_id))
    {
        //get header
        $set = getContentByCode("client_email_header");
        if(!$set->EOF)
            $msg_html = $set->fields["content_$lang"];
    }
    else 
    {
        //get header
        $set = getContentByCode("client_email_with_card_header");
        if(!$set->EOF)
            $msg_html = $set->fields["content_$lang"];
    }
    if( $country != "Schweiz" && !empty($trans_id))
    {
        //get header
        $set = getContentByCode("client_email_nonswiss_card");
        if(!$set->EOF)
            $msg_html = $set->fields["content_$lang"];
    }
    $msg_html = $this->replacePlaceHolders($msg_html, $customer);
    $msg_plain = strip_tags($msg_html);

    //get footer
    $set = getContentByCode("client_email_footer");
    if(!$set->EOF)
        $msg_html2 = $set->fields["content_$lang"];

    $msg_html2 = $this->replacePlaceHolders($msg_html2, $customer);
    $msg_plain2 = strip_tags($msg_html2);

    //get order
    $order = file_get_contents($file);

    $mail->Subject = (EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX ? EMAIL_SUBJECT_PREFIX." " : "")."Order from TERRA KERAMIK";
    $mail->Body = $msg_html."<br />".$order."<br />".$msg_html2;
    $mail->AltBody = $msg_plain.$msg_plain2;            
    //$mail->AddAttachment($file, date("d.m.Y H_i")." order.xls");
    $mail->AddAttachment($file, date("d.m.Y H_i")." ".mn_transliterate($customer["name"]." ".$customer["surname"].".pdf", $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf'));
    $mail->AddAddress($customer["email"], $customer["name"]." ".$customer["surname"]);
    $mail->Send();
```

I know there are similar questions, however the solutions they are offering don't help. Just trying my luck.

So, I've got this code which send a client an email plus adds an attachment. The attachment itself is a html table. It is also added into the email and looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqVsH.jpg)

When I receive an email the attachment is there but is corrupted or damaged. Other solutions advised to add "`$encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/pdf'`" along with file path and name.

This doesn't change situation at all. At the same time this code, which is currently commented
`//$mail->AddAttachment($file, date("d.m.Y H_i")." order.xls");` works pretty fine, I do receive an excel file with information.

Any thoughts?

Comment: application/octet-stream instead of application/pdf , assuming mail headers are mime type, use PHPMailer if it can make life easy ;)

Comment: *"The attachment itself is a html table."* - Instead of attaching the HTML table, why not just capture it with output buffering and attach the PDF only? I don't see the need to attach an HTML table.

Comment: @Sander, sure, I tried in gmail and win10 built-in client..Nothing.

Comment: @iSensical tried that as well, no success.. :(

Comment: Your code looks like it's been adapted from an obsolete example - are you using the latest PHPMailer? Does your `addAttachment` call return true?

Comment: @Synchro, yes, you are correct, the project i'm working on more than 5 years old, so the version is definitely obsolete.. would you advice installing newest version?

Comment: Yes, so long as you stay with the 5.2.x range, it should all work the same, but with fewer bugs, though look out for changes in the loading mechanism.

Comment: @MaxKool I flagged the question earlier in regards to my (then deleted) comment and [it has been undeleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39792903/cant-send-a-proper-pdf-file-via-phpmailer-addattachment#comment66878855_39792903). It's hard to say why that happened. Anyhow, reload the comments area and you'll see the 2nd one in there. Plus, as already stated; you seem to be using an older version of phpmailer. Visit https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer to download the latest copy. Here's the link for output buffering also http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php you may like that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks, man, issue is solved in another way. The mailer worked alright. Is there something I should press to close this question? The resolution was simple: I removed the html table from the mail and all was fine.